# Sectional curvature of tangent plane is preserved under exponential map

Tags: riemannian-geometry

> Let $\Pi$ be a non-degenerate tangnet plane to $M$ at $p$. If $P$ is a small enough neighbourhood of $0$ in $\Pi$, prove that $\exp_p(P)$ is a semi-Riemannian submanifold of $M$ whose Gaussian curvature at $P$ is $K(\Pi)$ where K is the sectional curvature of $M$.

I know that for a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ in $\Pi\subset T_pM$, then $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image in $M$.

So the diffeomorphism would preserve the semi-Riemannian manifold structure so that $\exp_p(P)$ is a submanifold of M.

So $T_pP$ and $T(\exp(P))$ are ismorphic.

Consider the following vectors of $T_p(\exp(P))$
$$v=\alpha^{\prime}(0)$$

$$w=\beta^{\prime}(0)$$

$$x=\gamma^{\prime}(0)$$

$$y=\lambda^{\prime}(0)$$

The Gauss equation is given by:

$$\left \langle\bar{R}_{v,w} x,y \right\rangle= \left \langle{R}_{v,w} x,y \right \rangle - \left \langle\Pi(v,x)\Pi(w,y) \right \rangle- \left \langle \Pi(w,x),\Pi(v,y) \right \rangle$$

Replacing the derivatives of the geodesics. I suppose the $\Pi=0$ since we are dealing with geodesics but that is only true if $\exp(P)$ is totally geodesic. Since $P$ is not assumed to be total geodesic.

How would I proceed?

**Question**:

Is what I have done correct? How do I finish my proof?

Thanks in advance.